# How to add clickable links inside a popup, in Bootstrap

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I have had no luck in finding a solution to this, on Google.
I am trying to add a link inside a popup. (I'm new to this and am using a template called NEON) My code looks like this:

```
<button type="button"
    class="btn btn-success"
    data-toggle="popover"
    data-trigger="click"
    data-placement="top"
    data-original-title="Facebook"
    datacontent="https://www.facebook.com/carparknorth"
><i class="entypo-check"></i></button>
```

The popup works fine, but how do I place the link inside the popup, so I will be able to click it, whenever the popup is open?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can change your `data-content` (you are missing a `-`) to open or link a new page inside an anchor href; to show HTML inside your popover you must use `data-html="true"` attribute.

Doc:

> Insert HTML into the popover. If false, jQuery's text method will be
>   used to insert content into the DOM. Use text if you're worried about
>   XSS attacks.

Ref: http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#popovers

Code:

```
<button type="button"
    class="btn btn-success"
    data-toggle="popover"
    data-trigger="click"
    data-original-title="Facebook"
    data-html="true"
    data-content="<a href='https://www.facebook.com/carparknorth'>facebook link</a>"
><i class="entypo-check"></i></button>
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/IrvinDominin/N5WTG/

Answer (score 0):

You can pass an array of options to the `$('#example').popover()` call, one of which is HTML. Check the docs on the TWBS website ... http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#popovers

If you don't want to manually make the JavaScript call, you could add `data-html="true"` to HTML element and it will be detected automagicall by Bootstrap.